# how to install vcpkg for vs code?

Tags: c++, c, vcpkg

I tried to install vcpkg for VS code and in a PowerShell Window. I had this error:

```
Could not find MSBuild version with C ++ support. VS2015, VS2017 or VS2019 (with C ++) must be installed.
```

So I installed Visual studio and I have the same error. What should I do?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/758

Answer (score 0):

Run `vcpkg integrate install` to customize `Visual Studio Code` on Linux or macOS. This command sets the location of the vcpkg enum and enables IntelliSense for the source files.

Look at this web page: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=msvc-160#integrate-with-visual-studio-code-linuxmacos

Comment: Correct link as of FEB-19 2023 is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/buildsystems/cmake-integration#visual-studio-code-cmake-tools-extension